# How do I resolve the circular reference in this LAG statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to use `LAG` to grab the last row's `EndingUnits` value and use it as the `OpeningUnits` for the current row. Part of the problem is that I can't use any of the aliases like `EndingUnits` or `OpeningUnits` in the select statement where they're defined. The other problem is the definition of `EndingUnits` relies on `OpeningUnits` which itself is dependent by `EndingUnits`.

The only table involved is `DividendPricing` which looks like this:

```
DividendPricingID PK, int
FiscalPeriod smalldatetime
DivPrice money
DivFactor float
```

-

```
OpeningUnits = LAG(EndingUnits, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod)
DRIP = (LAG(EndingUnits, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod))/DivPrice*DivFactor
EndingUnits = OpeningUnits + DRIP
```

My query looks like this, but obviously does not work:

```
SELECT FiscalPeriod,
    LAG(EndingUnits, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod) AS OpeningUnits,
    DivPrice,
    DivFactor,
    LAG(EndingUnits, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod)/DivPrice*DivFactor AS [DRIP],
    LAG(EndingUnits, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod) + (LAG(EndingUnits, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod)/DivPrice*DivFactor) AS EndingUnits
    FROM DividendPricing
```

Comment: What is the DDL of your base table(s)?

Comment: sounds like you need a recursive cte or running lag, no?

Comment: @TabAlleman added table definition

Comment: @scsimon I've never used a recursive CTE before, although I've heard of them. What is running lag? Is that different from using the LAG function?

Comment: What is the definition of `EndingUnits`/`OpeningUnits` in terms of the data in the table?   There's no `Units` column in the table at all.

Comment: @TabAlleman Well `OpeningUnits` is defined entirely as the previous value of `EndingUnits` with the the first row defaulting to a value of 1 since there's no previous row. `EndingUnits` is just the current row's `OpeningUnits + DRIP` or `pEndingUnits + (pEndingUnits/DivPrice*DivFactor)` where pEndingUnits is the previous row's `EndingUnits` value.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand the outcome you expect, however, to use the LAG() the way you intend, you have to pull it up from a starting point. I threw together this example using CTEs, perhaps it can help lead to an ideal solution in your case.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(FiscalPeriod SMALLDATETIME,DivPrice MONEY,DivFactor FLOAT)
INSERT @T VALUES
    ('01/01/2012',2,1.2),('04/01/2012',4,1.23),('07/01/2012',6,1.1),('10/01/2012',8,1.15),
    ('01/01/2013',2,1.2),('04/01/2013',4,1.23),('07/01/2013',6,1.1),('10/01/2013',8,1.15)

;WITH Start AS
(
    SELECT 
        EndingUnits = 1, FiscalPeriod,DivPrice, DivFactor 
    FROM 
        @T       
)
,NormalizedEnding AS
(
    SELECT 
        FiscalPeriod, DivPrice, DivFactor,
        EndingUnits = LAG(EndingUnits, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod) + (LAG(EndingUnits, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod) / DivPrice * DivFactor) 
    FROM 
        Start 
),
ContinuationCalulation AS
(
    SELECT
        FiscalPeriod,DivPrice,DivFactor,
        OpeningUnits =  LAG(EndingUnits, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod),
        DRIP = (LAG(EndingUnits, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod))/DivPrice*DivFactor,
        x=EndingUnits
    FROM
        NormalizedEnding
)
SELECT
    FiscalPeriod,DivPrice,DivFactor,OpeningUnits,
    EndingUnits = OpeningUnits + DRIP,
    x
FROM
    ContinuationCalulation
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The first two rows look right, and then it just repeats the same values over and over. I don't quite understand your method so I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm not sure if LAG is the right solution as I've been unable to get it to work after a week of attempts. Perhaps a cursor is necessary.